# Why isn't apache following my symbolic links?

Tags: permissions, centos, file-management, symbolic-link, apache-http-server

I need to link to a directory from `/var/www/html` to a directory within the home directory of a non-su user.  The operating is CENTos, the server is apache.  The config file for the directory is written like this:

```
<Directory [Redacted]>
Option FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

The permissions of files within the directory look like: 
`-rwxrwxr--`

The permissions of the (soft) symlink look like: 
`lrwxrwxrwx`

Nothing I do seems to make this work.  Do I need a `<Directory>` Entry for the directory which is being linked to?  I created one, identical to the entry above.  Regardless, all I see on the page is: **Forbidden**.

The files are meant to be downloaded, and are rather large, so if possible I'd avoid copying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure, you *might* need a `<Directory>` for the target as well. Trying won't hurt.

Also, Apache must have `+x` permissions for all parent directories of both the symlink and the target, as it is required to "descend" into a directory. Use the **`namei -l`** tool on the symlink to see a list of path components, and make sure that permission is present on all directories.

Comment: What permissions do you reccomend putting on it?  That works, but `777` probably isn't very smart in a live system

Comment: 771 works fine.  Could I assign it to the apache group and restrict perms even further?

Answer (score 2):

Using RHEL 8 I had a symlink into a user's directory which returned a 403 error.
I used `namei`, as suggested by [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686) which showed that `/home/user` was `drwx------`. I fixed it with `chmod a+rx /home/user/`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but it should be "Option**s**"

So:

```
<Directory [Redacted]>
Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

You can also use the '+' or '-' operators to keep valid syntax when mixing rules. i.e.

```
<Directory [Redacted]>
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
</Directory>
```